# Too many commas in this sentence?

Tags: commas, comma-splices

I don't know if this sentence is too long, or if it's okay to keep stringing phrases with commas. Any help would be great as my English is not so good.

> When I was using the toy truck as a reward for kids who finished all their chores, Mink would work harder than any other kid, just so that he could get a chance to play with the toy truck.

Comment: I'd remove the second comma. The sentence is long, but fine. Do you mean *chores*? You could use the simple past to shorten it up: was using/would work => used, worked.

Comment: Yes I sure did. Thanks for pointing that out. I also saw the other edits you made to my question and learned a good bit from those too. Thanks for that as well!

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: The repeat of 'the toy truck' sounds clumsy. I'd rewrite: 'I brought in a toy truck as a reward for kids who finished all their chores. Mink would work harder than all the other kids so that he would get to play with it.'

Answer (score -1):

*When I was using the toy truck as a reward for kids who finished all their chores, Mink would work harder than any other kid, just so that he could get a chance to play with the toy truck.*

I think I would phrase you sentence something like this:

*"I found that, when I offered children the chance to play with the toy truck, as a reward for completing all of their chores, Mink would work harder than any other child."*

This assumes that you are trying to explain what you found when you conducted the experiment.

Answer (score -4):

It is ok but too long for readers.

Use this

While I was using the toy truck as a reward for who finished all their choirs, Mink would worked harder than any other kid for playing with the toy truck. –

Comment: Could you suggest an improvement?

Comment: This (um) *was* a comment. Still, please visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)
 for guidance on answers, and how to use this site.

Comment: While I was using the toy truck as a reward for who finished all their choirs, Mink would worked harder than any other kid for playing with the toy truck.

Comment: Also, would work, not would worked, and other mistakes. I'm sorry, this is worse than the OP's sentence.